# How to highlight words within pure css multiline typewriter effect

Tags: css

How can I add a background colour to the words in bold, yet retain the existing typewriter animation?

The words currently marked within  tags I would like to highlight with a background colour.

```css
body {
  font-size:30px;
  padding:20px;
  background:#F7F7F7;
  color:#333;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  max-width: 900px;
}
.type {
  color:#0000;
  background:
    linear-gradient(-90deg,#333 5px,#0000 0) 10px 0,
    linear-gradient(#333 0 0) 0 0;
  background-size:calc(var(--n)*1ch) 200%;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box,text;
  background-clip: padding-box,text;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation: 
   b .7s infinite steps(1),   
   t calc(var(--n)*.05s) steps(var(--n)) forwards;
}
@keyframes t{
  from {background-size:0 200%}
}
@keyframes b{
  50% {background-position:0 -100%,0 0}
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="type" style="--n:200">Lorem ipsum dolor <strong>sit amet</strong>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet <strong>tincidunt</strong> urna. </span></h1>
```

Comment: I don't think that will be possible, with this kind of implementation. If you give the elements a background color, it will show up _before_ the text in these parts gets "revealed" already. The "typing" effect is made by making the background color (which is what actually gets animated here) of the container "shine through" in the places occupied by the text, that's what the `background-clip` property does.

Comment: a transparent box-shadow can get you closer `strong {
  box-shadow: 0 1lh inset rgb(255 255 0/50%);
}` but I don't know how you want it to behave with the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting the code in this way, it's possible to do:

```css
@keyframes typing {
    from { width: 100% }
    to { width: 0 }
    
}
strong {background-color: #ff0000;}
.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;  
}

.typing {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.hiders {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.hiders p {
  position: relative; 
  clear: both; 
  margin: 0;
  float: right; /* makes animation go left-to-right */
  width:0; /* graceful degradation: if animation doesn't work, these are invisible by default */
  background: white; /* same as page background */
  animation: typing 2s steps(30, end);
  animation-fill-mode: both;  /* load first keyframe on page load, leave on last frame at end */
}
  
.hiders p:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.hiders p:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.hiders p:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.hiders p:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<!-- container div is required to set absolute positions within it, so that .typing and .hiders exactly overlap -->

  <p class="typing">
    Lorem ipsum dolor <strong>sit amet</strong>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet <strong>tincidunt</strong> urna.
  </p>

  <div class="hiders">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Source: https://jsfiddle.net/hjwp/514cLzxn/